# Send message after triggered click event has fully finished

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to make my content script send the message containing data from the DOM with a certain delay.

On the page there's a log which has a button to show all entries on the same page. To trigger this, I use the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.showAll')[0].click();
});
```

On click, the page updates to show the whole list.

However I'm having a hard time timing sending of my payload after the updating of the page.

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
        'content': data,
        'title': "hello"
});
```

I tried to do it with a listener for the click on ".showAll" but that triggers it too early. I also tried using setTimeout(), but that didn't work very well either. What I'm looking for is some kind of "afterPageHasDoneItsThing"-listener.

Help much appreciated!

Comment: Can you add some more details/code? With a callback "afterPageHasDoneItsThing " you'll be able to accomplish what you want. If you add the chrome.runtime.sendMessage into the `click` listener callback, this should work.

Comment: I think you can do it without using jQuery. Like this: `window.addEventListener("load", function load(event){
    window.removeEventListener("load", load, false); 
    //send message once page loaded 
},false);`

Comment: Well, it proved it was all my stupidity causing the setTimeout() to not work properly. I had an error caused by the element disappearing after the clicking of the link. I guess I'm a bit unaccustomed to the debugging of javascript. Thanks all for your time and helpful comments.